# ComboBox Error: Could not set the Column property. Type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm using Excel VBA Userforms and I'm trying to fill a `ComboBox` but I'm receiving the error `Could not set the Column property. Type mismatch.`

The `ComboBox` has it's `ColumnCount` property set to `3`.

I'm using the code below to fill the `ComboBox`:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim varList As Variant

With UF_Main
    'Get CM list
    With .cbNAEmployee
        .Clear
        varList = fGetCMs
        If Not isArrayEmpty(varList) Then
            For i = LBound(varList, 2) To UBound(varList, 2)
                .AddItem varList(0, i)
                .Column(1, i) = varList(1, i)
                .Column(2, i) = varList(2, i)
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End With
```

The debugger flags the `With UF_Main` line as the offending line but this only occurs at the start of the third loop (it should loop 1000+ times).

When highlighting the line whilst debugging, it shows `<Object variable or With block variable not set>`.

There's nothing else occurring to change any of the properties within the UserForm / controls. What could be causing the error?

Comment: Is there any event code behind that control?

Comment: @Rory No there's no event code. I've used this method a good few times with no issue. I've tried adding the code to a new userform with a freshly created combobox and the same error is occurring meaning to me that it's specific to this block of code.

Comment: What data is in the array for the line that errors?

Comment: @Rory the array `varList` is filled from a function `fGetCms` that is a variant array filled from a recordset. Cheers

Comment: Yeah, but what data is in the array *for the line that errors*? Any null values or errors?

Comment: @Rory Ah sorry, the line that errors is `With UF_Main` which is just referencing the UserForm in question.

Comment: What's the declaration line for this procedure, how is it being triggered and where is the code located?

Comment: @Rory Thanks for your help. I've identified the issue - the recordset returns some `NULL` values which need to be handled prior to loading into the `ComboBox`.